# Matrix transformation in three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

What is wrong with this line?

```
myobejct.mesh.geometry.applyMatrix( new THREE.Matrix4().setTranslation( -10,-22,-30 ) );
```

I got Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'geometry' of undefined. I want to make some translations using matrix.

Answer (score 1):

It is not problem with matrix transformation. It is error show you that `myobejct.mesh` is undefined.